# modsecurity ssl certification project

Tags: https, ssl-certificate, webserver, mod-security

Mod-security_SSL_Certification

Hello evryone I'm setting up a new web server for attacks testing (dvwa) in my Centos machine and i want to set up an application security layer using `Mod_Security` module on Apache and its working great, now i want to change security from `http` to `https` using `SSL` certification and I don't know how to do this in the same machine.

Do I have to install any software, and where do I have to instal the certificates?  Does `mod_security` support `SSL` connection (HTTPS) ?? please help

Answer (score 0):

One of the benefits of using a WAF like ModSecurity which is integrated with your web server is that it doesn’t require any special handling for HTTPS. Just configure HTTPS in Apache (they are many tutorials online on how to do this) and ModSecurity can still read the traffic the same as it does for HTTP traffic.